# Does Linux kernel allocate free TCP port based on IP address?

Tags: linux-kernel, tcp, port

This is a hypothetical question, just to help me understand more about how TCP ports work.

Suppose I have multiple Ethernet cards on my machine and they are attached to different subnets. Now if I want to connect to a remote machine via TCP, without binding local address/port, kernel will determine the IP address and port for me.

My understanding is, kernel will choose the IP address based on the interface's primary IP, where the interface is chosen according to the routing table.

For the TCP port part, kernel will find an unused (ephemeral) port for me. Question is, does kernel keep used TCP ports by IP address or NOT? Meaning, if I have used port `a.b.c.d:12345` (suppose that's interface A's IP), and now a packet is supposed to go out from interface B, can I use `e.f.g.h:12345` (suppose that's interface B's IP)?

I can think of arguments for either way. Since an established TCP connection is identified by the local/remote IP/port 4-tuple, it seems the answer is `yes` - I can use port `12345` again. However, the kernel does not know the routing information (hence the interface, hence the source IP) when preparing the TCP layer, so it would be impossible for the kernel to assign an IP-dependent free TCP port at the TCP layer, before going down to the IP layer.

The kernel function [`inet_csk_get_port`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/net/ipv4/inet_connection_sock.c#L303) scans the `hinfo->bhash` table, which only uses port number for hash keys. Does that mean ephemeral ports are globally unique, and if that's true, it sounds like a (little bit of) waste of resource, for machines with multiple network cards on . Did I miss some important facts here? Hope someone can help me clarify this. Thanks!